# get ValueField from ComboBox

Tags: extjs

i have a grid with much entries, when i select an entry a new window with a form will open, which contains the values from the selected grid row. Now i can edit the parameters and save them into a database.

```
var form = btn.up().up().down('[name="eingabeformular"]').getForm();
form.getValues()
```

With the code above i will get all the data´s from my form entries, but only from the ComboBox, this will return ever the display field but i need the data´s!

is there any parameter in the Combobox or how can i do that??

Comment: Im not sure I follow your post. The form.getValues() should return the valueField of your combobox, not the displayField. Can you elaborate your question a little more?

Comment: How's your combo's model defined?